# Search my name in statement ! in c program using string functions

Tags: c, string, strcat, strstr

I need to know whats wrong with this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char a[50], b[100], c[5000];
    char *ret;
    //enter first name
    gets(a);
    //enter secend name 
    gets(b);
    //enter statement
    gets(c);

    strcat(a,b);

    if(strstr(c,a) != NULL) {
        printf("found your full name");
    } else {
        printf("not found your full name");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not work when, I use the following lines:

```
mohamed
ramadan
abdelrhmanamirelbatanonywoofymohamedramadanahmedalyomarelazazyahmedkamelahmedsa‌​lemessamelnaggarkhaledhelmy
```

It should find something, but the programm tells me, that it hasn't.

Comment: @MohamedHesham If your teacher/book told you to use `gets`, throw them out of a window.

Comment: [program tell me work "found your full name"](http://ideone.com/OkN5VR)

Comment: @MohamedHesham that program works, although it's not very good code. What is your  question? Did you put those "quotes" round your inputs? If so, it *won't* work.

Comment: @CarlProthman this it a problem which i try to solve it ..Input Format: 3 
First line is your first name
Second line is your last name
Third line contain the Geeks List

Output Format:
If you found your name in the list print "Invited" otherwise print "I don't have time for parties, I have thigs to do."

Sample Input:
line1: mohamed ;
line2: ramadan; 
line3 :abdelrhmanamirelbatanonywoofymohamedramadanahmedalyomarelazazyahmedkamelahmedsalemessamelnaggarkhaledhelmy;

Sample Output:
Invited

Comment: @szczurcio i will try to replace them if  problem with them not with me :)

Comment: format your question well enough for all to understand easily buddy.. there are options to distinguish code snippets from other parts and the like.

Answer (score 2):

- **Point 1**

  As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`

  > `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`
  >
  > If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable

  In your case,

  ```
  strcat(a,b);
  ```

  `a` *maybe* not having enough memory to hold the concatenated string. Possible UB. Change the logic.
- **Point 2**

  `gets()` suffers from buffer overflow issue. Use `fgets()` instead.